# open new vue page from vue homepage through button click so that contents of homepage dont appear

Tags: vue.js

Hi I am working on application built in vue. I have observed that whenever we route to new vue page from homepage(app page) using route, the contents of homepage are still visible in the next page such as heading i.e: new page loads with previous headings from homepage still visible. I want to completely open new vue page so that only contents of that page are visible(not the homepage or app page).please see below image for example
[image: Header from app page or homepage is visible in every page]

[image: Header from app page or homepage is visible in every page]

In above pics your can see that black header is common in every page. I want to open completely new page so that previous content don't show

Answer (score 0):

It was done by hiding the div which contains the contents of the homepage and displaying the div which contains the contents of the desired page. I used below code to hide or show the div

```
document.getElementById("id").style="display:none;" // if I want to hide a div 
document.getElementById("id").style="display:block;" // if I want to show a div
```